# Hit maximum timestamp count, will not record further events Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Hi so I am trying to run a simple app with a video player on Xcode and after a few seconds of running the following error shows up and the app is frozen.
 `nw_connection_add_timestamp_locked_on_nw_queue [C1] Hit maximum timestamp count, will not record further events` I have no idea what is creating this issue I even tried deleting the derived data.

Comment: Having same issue, did you every nail down the cause?

Comment: @Lkabo I could not nail down the exact cause for this issue, one thing is that it shows up when I run the app on the simulator, so I switched to testing on a real device and haven't run into this issue till now. Also, check this link where it says that this could be a simulator issue https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650741

Comment: Just started happening to me on 12/16/2022 using target hardware (iPhone).  Never seen before. Same exact obscure Xcode [C1] message as above.

Comment: 3 months later and it happened again but with [C3] this time:  nw_connection_add_timestamp_locked_on_nw_queue [C3] Hit maximum timestamp count, will start dropping events. Using target HW, not simulator.

Comment: Anyone ever figure this out, I am noticing this on both the simulator and physical device. For me it is a leaflet map and when moving the pin around on the map it starts throwing the 

[connection] nw_connection_add_timestamp_locked_on_nw_queue [C23] Hit maximum timestamp count, will start dropping events

Comment: And then obviously starts dropping the events and you can no longer move the pin on the map...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with your logging more than your app.

`You'll find your settings more than likely in /etc/asl/xxxxx`

In there for example, if you look at the `com.apple.clouddocs` file, it sets limits on the max file sizes.

Perhaps if you:

1. Run the app
2. run from terminal: `tail -f /var/log/system.log` you might get some more answers

Also check the amount of files in `/var/log` `/Library/Logs` '~/Library/Logs'

dont delete anything, rather use the in-built scripts to clear em.

You'd kick that off with:

`sudo periodic daily weekly monthly`

Doing tha ensures that the system deals with them as opposed to obliviously deleting them.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Having this same error message pop up after about a minute of my app running (different app altogether). I see this line in the log: Nov 26 12:39:28 MBP-4194 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0D000000-0500-0000-0000-000000000000[51749]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[87]